# Unable to access WordPress multisite, after assigning a domain name

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, multisite

I have installed a WordPress multisite by bitnami on AWS EC2, and then configures Route53 to assign a domain name to the website. I have been unable to access the subdomains created since then.

I get this error whenever i try to access the website. Even, the dashboard can't be reached.

I have updated the  .htaccess file as per the setting available in wordpress admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue. You have to add a new CNAME record in the DNS records with the subdomain name, pointing towards the website. Alternatively, you can also add a wildcard '*' CNAME to make sure your multisite works without issues.

Also, make sure where your DNS is being resolved if your DNS is being handled by your domain registrar, then you will have to make changes there.

Hope this helps.